# PHP and encapsulating MySQL rows into a JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

I'm playing with a guestbook/chatroom idea and have a MySQL table setup with three columns:

1 - id - Primary Key auto increment

2 - name - String

3 - comment - string

I have very little experience with PHP but this is what I've put together for this operation:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM guestbook");
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
      //add the row to the $chat array at specific index of $i
      $chat[$i] = $row;
      $i += 1;
  }

$encode = json_encode($chat);
echo "$encode";
```

However, output from this looks pretty awful:

```
[{"0":"1","id":"1","1":"Justin ","name":"Justin ","2":"Comment 1","comment":"Comment 1"},
{"0":"2","id":"2","1":"Justin ","name":"Justin ","2":"Another comment","comment":"Another comment"},
{"0":"3","id":"3","1":"Justin ","name":"Justin ","2":"Look at this comment!","comment":"Look at this comment!"},
{"0":"4","id":"4","1":"Justin ","name":"Justin ","2":"Ok I'm done talking","comment":"Ok I'm done talking"}]
```

I was hoping to get three fields: id, name, and comment, but it looks like things doubled.  Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To paraphrase Marc, Just replace this line:

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))`

With this:

`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))`

To get cleaner JSON. By default `mysql_fetch_array()` will return both an integer index and an associative index, you only want the associative index.

Answer (score 3):

mysql_fetch_array returns a compound array: indexed AND keyed. To fetch just one or the other, use `mysql_fetch_row()` (indexed only), `mysql_fetch_assoc()` (keyed only), or use the extra argument on [fetch_array](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) to specify which you want: `mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_BOTH);`

Comment: so would the correct answer just be to json_encode($result);, because I tried that and it just echoed "null".

Comment: No, the correct answer would be to use mysql_fetch_assoc() in your while() loop, then json_encode $chat as usual. That'll produce JUST the named id/name/comment key:value pairs in the JSON data.

Comment: I don't understand, can you copy/paste my code and insert the syntax you're describing? I'm concerned with what the put inside the parentheses in mysql_fetch_assoc(), and if I should still be adding to $chat[$i].